# How to Reinstall or Remove Wacom Drivers

Tags: drivers, uninstall, tablet, wacom, reinstall

I'm a new user banging my head against the wall trying to get my Wacom tablets to work on Kubuntu 14.04. I have two tablets: a bigger, older Intuos 2, and a smaller, much newer Intuos Pen Small. I tried following all the guides I could find on here and the Wacom Linux Project wiki, but I couldn't get my Intuos 2 to work at all.

After a while, I decided to see if my Intuos Pen Small would work out of the box, as some other forum goers have mentioned. When I plug it in, I immediately get cursor functionality, however I can't change any settings. In the Graphic Tablet - KDE Control Module window, I get an error saying "Graphic Tablet Error: Profile Default Does Not Exist". If I try to make a new profile, it gives me the same error, replacing the above "Default" with whatever I tried to name it.

I'm thinking maybe, somewhere on the long winding path I took trying to get my old Intuos 2 working, I messed something up. I want to try reinstalling everything all over from scratch. Unfortunately, I don't really know where to start, and I can't find any guides for this online. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a KDE tool for configurations on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The system drivers provided with Ubuntu (even the 16.04 one) don't work. If you install from
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom
like I just did, and follow all instructions to the letter, your Intuos 2 will start working just as well as mine just did. I've almost given up on having my digital pen working again. I didn't un-install anything, I simply downloaded, compiled and installed from that URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP asked how to *ununstall* drivers, not how to install them from some url